# Rendering text that includes newline character

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render the following in my controller:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Currently it looks like this:

```
User-agent: *Disallow: /

def robots
  output = "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /"   #this is wrong I know...
  render text: output
end
```

How can I include the newline character?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you use double quotes `render :text => "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /"`

Comment: Actually when I view source on the page it looks fine, but not in the browser for some reason, strange.

Comment: How are you looking at the result? A browser may not show the line break even though it's there.

Comment: Check this out, might help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Line-break_handling.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what was posted by OP?